# Limiting IO interval in FIO

Tags: performance, solid-state-drive

I would like to limit I/O in FIO to let's say 1 write every 30ms for example. I can't find any configuration setting that allows me to limit this.  Is this even possible?

I tried using the Interval settings, but didn't seem to do the trick.